# How to design a python 2.7 code that stores in a dictionary the following pairs: items of given list = whether the item is a palindrome

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

```
fl = [25, 33, 287, 454]
palydict = {}

for i in fl:
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        palydict.update(str(i) = "paly")
    else:
        palydict.update(str(i) = "not paly")
print (palydict)

File "main.py", line 5
    palydict.update(str(i) = "paly")
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Could somebody please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `update` incorrectly.  Fortunately, you don't need to use it at all to add an item to a dictionary.

```
fl = [25, 33, 287, 454]
palydict = {}

for i in fl:
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
        palydict[i] = "paly"
    else:
        palydict[i] = "not paly"
print palydict
```